# In grails app, the field in service is shared by user or not?

Tags: grails

I have a question about the field in service is shared by user or not? My grails version is 2.3.4.
Now I have a controller with two actions and trying to set and get value from service field.

```
//This is a controller
class TestController{
  def testService

  def setValue(){
    testService.setValue("123")
  }

  def getValue(){}
    println testService.getValue()
  }
}

//This is a service
class TestService{
  def var

  def setValue(def value){
    var = value
  }

  def getValue(){}
    return var
  }
}
```

In other words, if several users are using the action `getValue` in the controller, do they share the `var` in the service or not?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default all [services](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/services.html) are singletons, so there is only one instance of service per webapp, but functions inside are not synchronised:

> By default, access to service methods is not synchronised, so nothing prevents concurrent
>   execution of those methods. In fact, because the service is a
>   singleton and may be used concurrently, you should be very careful
>   about storing state in a service. Or take the easy (and better) road
>   and never store state in a service.
>
> You can change this behaviour by placing a service in a particular
>   scope. The supported scopes are:
>
> ```
> prototype - A new service is created every time it is injected into another class
> request - A new service will be created per request
> flash - A new service will be created for the current and next request only
> flow - In web flows the service will exist for the scope of the flow
> conversation - In web flows the service will exist for the scope of the conversation. ie a root flow and its sub flows
> session - A service is created for the scope of a user session
> singleton (default) - Only one instance of the service ever exists
> ```

Comment: Thanks Michal. I was wondering if I add `static scope = "session"` to the service, does that means every user has its own `var`?

Comment: That means every HTTP session would have it's own instance of the service. Thus, any value of a property of an instance would be specific to that HTTP session. Provided your users are one per session then yes, each user session would have their own.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore! It helps me a lot.

Comment: @johanzhou be careful with session scope - there are some restrictions connected with mixing different types of services. always test it!

Comment: @MichalSzulc Thanks for your suggestion.